# elasticsearch 7 and mapping and sorting

Tags: elasticsearch

I struggle a lot with achieving sorting in ES 7. I always seem to receive
`Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on ...`
I also created a mapping, where I turn fielddata on,  but somehow, it brings no change.

```
{
    "index": "orderoverview",
    "body": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "CUSTREFNR": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "ORDERNR_EVO": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I must say, the removal of types in ES 7 is not very clear to me. 
By indexing, I must provide a type:

```
'index' => getIndexName(),
    'type' => 'Orderoverview',
    'body' => []
```

Here, if I provide my type I get the error: `Rejecting mapping update to [index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, Orderoverview]"}]`

So I index them with type _doc, but then the searches don't work anymore.

```
"index": "orderoverview",
    "type": "_doc",
    "body": {
        "from": 0,
        "size": 20,
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "CUSTNR": "24508"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ES is great, but sometimes feels like black magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any modification to existing fields it is always advisable to delete the index and re-ingest the document once again. This may not be the case when you add new fields though as mentioned by @Amit in the comment.

Another point is its better to make use of `keyword` field instead of setting fielddata to true for text fields as mentioned in this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#before-enabling-fielddata).

Secondly in your question, you've specified different fields in mapping (CUSTREFNR, ORDERNR_EVO) and you are querying on different field(CUSTNR). Make sure you notice on little things.

Below is the sample mapping, documents, query request and response.

### Mapping:

Instead of enabling `fielddata=true`, create [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html). You can read about them in the link mentioned. Below is how your mapping would be:

```
PUT orderoverview
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "CUSTREFNR": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "ORDERNR_EVO": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that for both the fields I've ended up creating its sibling `keyword` field.

You can read about [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) and [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) datatypes in the respective links.

Just to make a note, use `keyword` for *aggregation* and *sorting* functionalities, and `text` for typical searching.

Again when it comes to exact matches leverage `keyword` using [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html).

On another note, you should not specify type in your mapping in ES 7. From [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) link, we have the below note:

> Specifying types in requests is deprecated. For instance, indexing a
>   document no longer requires a document type. The new index APIs are
>   PUT {index}/_doc/{id} in case of explicit ids and POST {index}/_doc
>   for auto-generated ids. Note that in 7.0, _doc is a permanent part of
>   the path, and represents the endpoint name rather than the document
>   type.

This means, the only acceptable value during ingestion would be `_doc`. Anything other than that, your ingestion would fail.

### Sample Documents:

```
POST orderoverview/_doc/1
{
  "CUSTREFNR": "24508",
  "ORDERNR_EVO": "A1B1"
}

POST orderoverview/_doc/2
{
  "CUSTREFNR": "24508",
  "ORDERNR_EVO": "A1B2"
}

POST orderoverview/_doc/3
{
  "CUSTREFNR": "24508",
  "ORDERNR_EVO": "A2B2"
}

POST orderoverview/_doc/4
{
  "CUSTREFNR": "24509",
  "ORDERNR_EVO": "A1B1"
}
```

### Sample Query:

Let's say you have a use case where you'd want to select all documents having 24508 as `CUSTREFNR` however you would want to sort them by `ORDERNR_EVO`, then below is how your query would be:

```
POST orderoverview/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "CUSTREFNR": "24508"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "ORDERNR_EVO.keyword": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "orderoverview",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "CUSTREFNR" : "24508",
          "ORDERNR_EVO" : "A2B2"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "A2B2"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "orderoverview",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "CUSTREFNR" : "24508",
          "ORDERNR_EVO" : "A1B2"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "A1B2"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "orderoverview",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "CUSTREFNR" : "24508",
          "ORDERNR_EVO" : "A1B1"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "A1B1"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't get why you mentioned any changes in mapping requiring the re-index, for incremental changes like adding a new field doesn't require deleting the index and re-index at all.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal Yes you are right. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thank you!!

Comment: Hi, that's a super answer. I must say I have already fixed it. It was that my mapping was actually not re-updated, indeed, little things. I will accept your answer, just for the effort. It's more than I could do :) For the record, "  "fielddata": true" was enough to engage sorting functions.